# How create different port mapping by endpoints in Docker?

Tags: docker, containers, devops, virtualization, docker-network

I have problem with connecting two networks to container by differently port for each network.

Scheme:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIZOV.png)

I must create container C2 and network bridge1.
C2 must be accessible from default bridge by port 80 and bridge1 by port 8000.

I've tried run C2 with published 80:80

```
docker network create -d bridge --subnet 10.0.12.0/24 bridge1
docker run -itd --name C2 -p 80:80 nginx
```

and connect C2 to bridge1

```
docker network connect docker1 C2
```

but then i can't add port mapping 8000:80 for bridge1.

Second idea was create two port mapping:

```
docker network create -d bridge --subnet 10.0.12.0/24 bridge1
docker run -itd --name C2 -p 80:80 -p 8000:80 nginx
docker network connect docker1 C2
```

But now I can't specify which port is for the default network and which is for bridge1.
Both are available on both networks.

I looked for in documentation but found nothing.

Comment: What leads to those exact requirements?  Inside the Docker network, as an implementation detail, each container will have its own IP address, so there shouldn't be port conflicts, and you can't remap ports within Docker space.

Comment: Also maybe you'd be interested in specifying your docker-network mapping in a declarative way in a [`docker-compose.yml`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) file, and using [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers.
This is homework and that why i have those exact requirements. 
I can't use compose because it has to be bash script (terminal docker commands)